PC has no Signal, Mouse and Keyboard won't work
I'm having some issues. Recently, I updated all my drivers to the latest version. After all of the drivers were updated to 100%, I went back to restart my PC. After that, it showed no signal, the mouse and keyboard had no signal, or it wouldn't work. Also, I tried to turn off my PC, but it went back on itself. It beeps twice after it turns on, and I don't know what to do. I can't fix this type of problem; I need help.
 

If it beeps twice something is wrong, and those codes depend on brand - we'll need to know what your PC is to know what's wrong, or for you to check the manual

My PC is Acer Veriton X2660G

Could be a problem with the CMOS battery on the motherboard?

Manual's here but its worse than useless https://www.acer.com/us-en/support/product-support/Veriton_X2660G

Thanks for the manual i might need it later, but for now the current problem is i can't access the bios without my keyboard and no display, it could be in the motherboard problem nor something i need to check, all the USB ports is not receiving any signal.

Battery seems like a good bet, and at its age you ought to replace it anyway. Its a cheap/simple thing to check

Ima check it and clean my PC first, i bought my PC 2nd hand so something like this could happen, or it might be the Updated driver was bugged. Thanks for the assistance @JourneymanGeek
